# Necessity of CSRF Protection with ID Token Authentication in Firebase

Tags: csrf

I recently came across a statement in the Firebase documentation that suggests "CSRF protection should be taken into account." This guidance appears in the context of using an ID token for authentication. My understanding is that when authenticating with an ID token, CSRF protection might not be necessary. However, the document recommends considering CSRF protection for the sessionLogin endpoint.

```
app.post('/sessionLogin', (req, res) => {
  // Get the ID token passed and the CSRF token.
  const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
  const csrfToken = req.body.csrfToken.toString();
  // Guard against CSRF attacks.
  if (csrfToken !== req.cookies.csrfToken) {
    res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
    return;
  }
  // Set session expiration to 5 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
  // Create the session cookie. This will also verify the ID token in the process.
  // The session cookie will have the same claims as the ID token.
  // To only allow session cookie setting on recent sign-in, auth_time in ID token
  // can be checked to ensure user was recently signed in before creating a session cookie.
  getAuth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
    .then(
      (sessionCookie) => {
        // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
        const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };
        res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success' }));
      },
      (error) => {
        res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
      }
    );
});
```

Could someone explain why CSRF protection is deemed necessary in this scenario, despite using an ID token for authentication? Is there a specific security vulnerability that this protection is addressing?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

Comment: Identification tokens do not authenticate a person. They identify a person. A typical use case for Cross-Site Request Forgery is: An attacker has your system create an ID token, then tricks your user to access your site with their ID token. Your user will then authenticate, and the attacker hopes that they can now use the ID token as though they are an authenticated user. With this CSRF prevention method, the authentication will fail because your user didn't get the CSRF token part. You **MUST** also invalidate the ID token after authentication even with CSRF tokens.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I hadn't considered the attack vector where an attacker uses their own ID token to authenticate a user.

Answer (score 1):

This is specifically trying to prevent login CSRF. Login CSRF is a special class of CSRF attacks where the attacker has credentials - in this case, an ID token - that are valid for your site, and "tricks" the victim's browser into completing the login process with those credentials. The victim is now logged in using an attacker-controlled account, so any actions they take actually go on the attacker's account. In some cases, you can even do this in the middle of an existing session, effectively swapping the victim's session out from under them.

The usefulness of this attack depends on the site, and on the victim's expectation. If it's a site where the user is expected to upload private data, login CSRF can be a way to get access to the victim's uploads (specifically, uploads made while they're logged into your account), but if the victim goes looking for their own past uploads, they'll quickly notice that those are missing. Similarly, for a shopping site, if the user expects their payment info to already be saved then they will probably notice right away that it isn't (or they'll use your payment info, which is obviously undesirable), but if they don't expect it to be saved yet then they might enter (and save) their payment info to your account, letting you use it again later.

Many sites don't bother with login CSRF protection. If the site is one where it'd be immediately obvious to the victim that they aren't in their usual account (e.g. browsing social media, where the attacker-controlled account isn't following the same people), or where the attacker has nothing to gain from "letting" somebody else use their account (e.g. an online forum, where the "victim's" post might appear under the wrong name but this probably isn't useful to the attacker), it's totally reasonable to skip including it. On the other hand, sometimes a *targeted* login CSRF can be valuable. It'd normally be obvious that somebody isn't signed into the correct email account, but if they are only composing an email rather than looking at their received mail, a login CSRF against the right person could let you read the email they just sent, which might be worth the hassle of the attack.

It's also hard securely prevent login CSRF. The usual approach is the "double-submit cookie" pattern (as seen in the example code), but that's a relatively weak pattern. The anti-CSRF token is not tied to an account (because nobody is logged in yet) and the server can't validate it except against the request body (or maybe header), so any cookie-planting attack can be used to bypass the protection. Also sometimes there are other ways to force a user to be logged in under a different account anyhow (such as a cookie-planting attack where the attacker's session cookie is planted instead), or abusing SSO if they didn't implement CSRF protection there. Some sites even explicitly allow sending credentials in a single request, e.g. to facilitate automated logins, which is essentially login CSRF by design. However, anything that raises the bar for the attacker will reduce risk to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation on Login CSRF, I wasn't aware of it!